# Home automation in C#?

Tags: c#, automation, home-automation

I want to develop a small C# application to control various components of a central heating.

First, I would like to be able to retrieve values ​​from a temperature sensor. I must not be the first C# developer looking to get this kind of stuff. I would then try to control thermostatic valves.

Microsoft or others vendors delivers GUI libraries, Mathematics libraries, database access libraries, ... I'm just looking for a Home Automation Library or something similar. Could you redirect me to the hardware components compatible or information sites on the subject.

Thank you,

Comment: Closed and 8 users already added this question to their favorites?

Comment: The problem with home automation is that some people think that talking about this subject on a developer forum is off topic. With this attitude you never get information because (believe me) talking about programmation on a Home Automation forum is useless.

Comment: I don't really agree on the close even if it's not a specific programming question it's still more related to what to choose as a programmer.. and you did specify C#

Comment: Microsoft or others vendors delivers GUI libraries, Mathematics libraries, database access libraries, ... I'm just looking for a Home Automation Library or something similar (because I know there is still no Home Automation Libraries for C#)

Comment: I agree with, seems like it is on topic. The question is pretty well defined and he's asking for specific C# libraries and implementation. @Dran, I guess you could edit your question to ask about the libraries.

Comment: @StefanE, I hope someone adds that last reopen vote :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm playing around with a .NET development board with great fun for home automation. They come in all price ranges(some very simple and there are the ones with screens, wifi and so on) and support a compact .net framework and have a lot of sensors and relays to add on to it!

[NetDuino](http://www.netduino.com/)

My own project at home is that I just had a on/off switch for my warm water. I do control it with my netduino board by a fixed times but I can also switch it on from a web browser. Next version is for it to not switch on if there have been no movement in my apartment for a while so if I go off for holiday I don't have to switch it off. Also bought an servo to open my window if temp go over a certain degree :).. Next will be to have some kind recognition if a lady enters to start the soft music and the disco ball spinning!

Comment: Here is the home site: http://www.netduino.com/

Comment: Agree, better link and I updated my post..

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft released a microcontroller that is programmable in .NET about a month ago.

It is called [Gadgeteer](http://www.netmf.com/gadgeteer/)

Comment: Gadgeteer is much more oriented toward schools and experiments, than for creating a stand-alone project. However, despite the high price, it should be a quick way to assemble hardware blocks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the party, but these guys have been doing some interesting work.  I downloaded the source and poked around a bit, and have chatted on their site: http://www.opensourceautomation.com/

A lot of out of the box functionality, open source, and active.

Answer (score 3):

While this is not in C#, you can use an Arduino to do this kind of thing. There is lots of help out there for Arduinos. They can be very powerful. They use a C++ ish language which is similar enough to C# that you could pick it up.

Some sites:

http://diyistheway.blogspot.com/2009/03/thermosmart.html

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage

Comment: Interesting but I'm not lokking for a thermostat. If fact I would like to create a software thermostat. My computer is the thermostat. How do you turn on/off the valves ?

Comment: There are 10 I/O pins for you to program as you please. You could have a different valves on each of those pins (or multiple pins depending on the valve, but there are 10 available). Or you could put another shield on top of that board that has a ton of I/Os for all your many controls. With this ethernet board you can have it hooked up to your network directly. http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet. There are also bluetooth boards, wifi boards, USB only...etc. The options are endless with these things.

Comment: Although @StefanE's answer is pretty awesome too. It looks like it is basically an Arduino but you can work with it in C# directly. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

CRESTRON
their whole product line is based of software developed in .net (probably c# but could be vb)
and all they do is control systems (hvac, lighting, etc....)

most of the systems they control run on three different types of interfaces:
serial (232, terminal),
digital (usually over tcp/ip), or
analog

you need to find out what kind of interface your hvac system has, then find a way to plug your computer up to it, then program in c# using that protocal

Answer (score 1):

[Telldus](http://www.telldus.se/) provide interfaces to wireless control and they have [c# libraries](http://developer.telldus.se/browser/trunk/tellstick.net)

Answer (score 0):

Crestron is in the process of release a new SDK that uses a sandboxed version of C# to control their extensive selection of home automation hardware.

Unfortunately, using their software requires special permission and training.